# Error installing required packages in Yosemite

Tags: installation, upgrade, homebrew, requirements

I'm trying to install ruby 2.1.0, but when the `install.sh` is running I am constantly getting the following error

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install automake libtool gcc49 libyaml readline libksba',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1433830031/package_install_automake_libtool_gcc49_libyaml_readline_libksba.log
+ case "$1" in
+ [[ -t 1 ]]
+ return 1
+ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.
```

I have already run `brew tap --repair` command and nothing is solved. I also got the following warning

```
Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation
+ case "$_system_version" in
+ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Does anybody have any ideas?